# second derivative of exponential $e^{x^2}+3x-2$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I have to find the first and second derivative of $e^{x^2}+3x-2$, the first one i can do ok but can someone please help me with the second.

thanks

Comment: ok when you get the first derivative, you will need the product rule

Comment: Is that edit correct, or did you mean: $e^{x^2+3x-2}$?

Comment: @loveday LIewellyn please review answers

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=e^{x^2}+3x-2$$
$$f'(x)=2xe^{x^2}+3$$
use the product rule $\frac{d}{dx}u(x)g(x)=v(x)\frac{d}{dx}u(x)+u(x)\frac{d}{dx}v(x)$
$$f''(x)=2(e^{x^2}+2x.xe^{x^2})$$

Comment: both answer is great

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative is: $2x e^{x^2}+3$

The second derivative is the derivative of the above equation: $$2x \left({\frac{d}{dx}e^{x^2}}\right) + \left({\frac{d}{dx}2x}\right)e^{x^2}+\left({\frac{d}{dx}3}\right)= 2x(2x e^{x^2})+2e^{x^2}+0=4x^2e^{x^2}+2e^{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

some rules,first  $e^{f(x)}$'s derivative is  $$e^{f(x)}*f'(x)$$,then $(f*g)'=f'*g+g'*f$,so  you should use both rule for find first,second and  infinite order derivative